# Recognizing Object dependancies for creation in Vulkan

Tags: object, dependencies, vulkan

In general, I want to know how exactly I can find the dependencies of a particular object, and the time of creation and termination of an object in Vulkan?

For more explanation, I bring an example, as far as I have seen, all the Vulkan examples create shaders in process of creating their pipelines, but when you see at its creation info structure and its creator function there is no dependency except logical device.
So in this theory I can create shader modules when I have logical device while this is in contradiction with seen examples.

Comment: Well, the Vulkan specification is your friend. I did not understand your Q much though. You are in charge of creating and destroying objects yourself (through `vkCreate*` and `vkDestroy*`). Generally you can create anytime you want (as long as you have valid arguments to provide). You can destroy when the object is not in "use" and all of its "children" are already destroyed.

Comment: The "time of creation and termination" for Vulkan objects is defined quite clearly in the API. As for "dependencies of a particular object", I have no idea what you're talking about here. Pipelines are not in any way "dependent" on a shader object. Creating a pipeline *requires* a compiled shader, but that's different from saying that pipelines are "dependent" on shaders. After the pipeline is created, the shader object is no longer needed (for that pipeline).

Comment: Thanks for your comments, so, every time I want to create an object I must look at its Vk*CreateInfo and the arguments that is used in its create function. More specifically for my example, I want to load my shaders while I'm loading my scene and after that I create my pipeline.